# Customizing Java packages JAXB wsimport

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm trying to generate a client with maven and jaxb from a wsdl file with 2 schemas inside and some elements with the same name from different schemas

When I try to execute the compilation I'm getting the next error:

```
Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
```

**WSDL schemas**:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://ws.services" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">...</schema>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://ws.models" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">...</schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

I tried renaming the elements that produce the error, but **then my spring client receive the correct SOAP message, but it doesn't populate the response object properly (all its attributes are null)**. I guess the problem might come from renaming the response classes, so that's why I'm trying to generate different packages keeping the original name of all the classes.

In order to do that, I wrote the next bindings file but I don't know what I'm doing wrong that it is not working.

**bindings.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"  
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"  
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"  
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >  

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mywsdl.wsdl#types?schema1"
    node="/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://ws.services']">  
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>  
            <jaxb:package name="package1" />  
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>  
</jaxb:bindings>  

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mywsdl.wsdl#types?schema2"
    node="/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://ws.models']">  
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>  
            <jaxb:package name="package2" />  
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>  
</jaxb:bindings> 

</jaxb:bindings>
```

My configuration part in the maven file is the next, just in case it is useful:

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <wsdlLocation>wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
    <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
    <wsdlFiles>
        <wsdlFile>mywsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    </wsdlFiles>
    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</bindingDirectory>
    <bindingFiles>
        <bindingFile>bindings.xml</bindingFile>
    </bindingFiles>
    <packageName>original.package</packageName>
    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
</configuration>
```

When I compile with this bindings files, the same error appears. So I think that maybe it isn't right.

Do you find any mistakes?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a tip: you can remove the "bindingFiles" configuration section entirely if you place all your binding files in src/jaxws! They will then be picked up by the jaxws-maven-plugin automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my experience it is best to create 2 binding files (one for each WSDL file).
Update your pom.xml accordingly and make sure that the root element of the binding files is jaxws:bindings (and not jaxb:bindings!)

**Some hints:**

1. Make sure to set the "wsdlLocation" attribute correctly! It must point to the WSDL file using a relative path!
2. The jaxws:package determines the package that will be used for the generated service classes. (the stuff annotated with @WebService)
3. Enable or disable wrapperStyle and asyncMapping as you wish. ;-)

Example binding file for "package1":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
                    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    wsdlLocation="mywsdl.wsdl"
                    version="2.0">

        <jaxws:package name="package1"/>
        <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
        <jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>true</jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>

        <jaxws:bindings node="//wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://ws.services']">
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="package1"/>
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        </jaxws:bindings>

    </jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, that did the trick. Important!, when I compiled the first time the plugin ignored my new package configuration because it was using the previous one from my pom file, once I've removed `<packageName>original.package</packageName>` it created different packages. However... Spring is not populating my response object properly and I can see in my logger that the response SOAP message is correct, so this solution didn't solve my main problem.

Comment: Using `node` attribute for `jaxws:bindings` seemed to be important.